# Alternative Email Provider

Tags: email, privacy

As a continuation to [Why would someone trust DuckDuckGo or other providers with a similar privacy policy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12664/why-would-someone-trust-duckduckgo-or-other-providers-with-a-similar-privacy-pol) it seems like we already have a secure way to make a search without writing history and etc. at least it's written in duckduckgo privacy policy.

My question is do we have the same alternative for Gmail, which at least assures that he doesn't read our email's and then offer an adv based on them and so on. I am looking for alternative for Gmail for which privacy and security is the main thing.

Comment: **Sneakermail**, really. Or pigeon mail. Do you expect someone who's in it for the money to value **your privacy**? And when money is not enough, there's also PATRIOTism and gentle pressure from authorities to help them.

Comment: Welcome to [Security.SE]! Unfortunately, this question is essentially asking for product/service recommendations, which is off-topic on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Why this must be offtopic, because asnwer would represent subjective opinion? It doesnt have to if it would be backed up with tests and comparisions. In my opinion this is a very good and needed question

Comment: @Buksy subjective means opinion based and is considered off topic on stack exchange.

Comment: yes, I just tried to tell, if it will be backed up by tests and comparisions, it will be no more subjective, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

*Promises* of anonymity are only as good as they get. If you want to have some reasonable guarantee that your email contents won't be read by the email provider, then *encryption* is the right tool. See [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/) and [S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME). In any case, an email is between *two* persons, and even if you have a "privacy-preserving" provider on your side, you cannot have the same guarantee for the provider used by the people you send emails to, and receive emails from. There is no guarantee of protection for emails in transit, either; only encryption will bring you a comprehensive solution for the whole emailing system.

Of course, regardless of encryption and other measures, an email must still be **transmitted**, which means that outsiders can still see the destination address, which can be [quite revealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

The standard approach here is to host your own mail server. I wouldn't want to give the impressions that this is trivial, but it is certainly very do-able. (Unlike trying to run your own Internet search engine would be!)